# iOS: Sinch SDK Instant Messaging Issue(SINErrorDomainCapability error 2001)

Tags: ios, instant-messaging, sinch

I am integrating sinch sdk in my iOS application.
it's giving me error of SINErrorDomainCapability error 2001.

Will you please tell me how to resolve it.
i am new to social integration.

Comment: No.
Currently i am using iOS 8;

Comment: What URL are you hitting? And when do you get this?

Comment: i didn't know where you hit the url in sinch?

Comment: When you start the client or when you send a message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you set up the right capabilities when starting the Sinch client, as documented here: https://www.sinch.com/docs/instant-message/ios/#sinchclient